# Rails ignoring select sql when ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

When a user lands on the page, I have the call:

```
@objects = Object.select("objects.*, MAX(votes.updated_at) AS 
               mv").joins(:votes).group("objects.id").
               order("mv DESC").includes(:categories)
```

This works great.

However, I have an ajax call for sorting and when it calls the exact same command, I run into an error saying 'mv is not a column' and this is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, objects.id AS objects_id FROM "objects" 
       INNER JOIN "votes" ON "votes"."object_id" = "objects"."id" 
       GROUP BY objects.id ORDER BY mv DESC
```

Why does the same command have the select call ignored completely. It replaces it only with count_all and objects_id?

Comment: I don't see the connection between your `Object.select...` and that `select count(*) ...` query.

Comment: Exactly. It adds that in on its own and totally ignores the select statement. If I take out the group() command, it works, but doesn't group them. Is this a bug in rails?

Comment: I'd expect PostgreSQL to complain with that GROUP BY unless you're using 9.2. Are you sure your AJAX call is using that?

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to get the group by working after converting from mysql. This works though. As I say above, it's odd that it works in the controller on the page load. However, when I called another controller action via ajax, the exact same command is converted to something that ignores the select() parameter and adds the count(*). I'm using postgres 9.1.4

Answer (score 1):

It might be because mv is not select for 'output'
so do `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, mv, ...`

Comment: It still ignores everything in the .select() rails call. I can add anything to .select("objects.*, MAX(votes.updated_at) AS mv, blah blah blah") and it just ignores it all.